# Assignment of variables within function

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I recently found a quirk in the R language and I am not sure if this is intended or a bug.

Below is an example:

```
# Simple print function
print.func <- function(n) {print(n)}

# Test it out
print.func(1:10)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

# However, if we wrap an assignment into the function
print.func(a <- 1:10)
```

What I do not understand is that within the `print.func`, all assignments should be confined to the local function environment, but in this case, `a` gets assigned in the global environment.

I would expect this behaviour only if we do something like `print.func(a <<- 1:10)`.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: `a <- print.func(1:10)`

Comment: the assignment is not in the local environment, it's done prior to the function call, in the global environment

Comment: @Cath If you have some documention/material to back that up, it would be a good answer.  With regard to why his call still prints the numbers, `a <- 1:10` itself returns the vector 1:10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented behavior.

See the R Language Definition [Section 4.3.3](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-evaluation):

> It is also worth noting that the effect of `foo(x <- y)` if the argument
>   is evaluated is to change the value of `x` in the calling environment
>   and not in the evaluation environment of `foo`.

In your example the calling environment is the global environment.